# Laptop charges the battery only when power-off

Tags: battery, charging, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo Ideapad Z710. It is 5 months old. This started to happen yesterday. While I'm on Windows 8.1 it says that the battery is charging but in reality it is discharging. However, when I shut-down Windows it is charging.

What can I do?

Comment: How do you know it's actually discharging when it says it's charging?

Comment: @RsyaStudios, because the battery percentage decreases as time passes. As if it is not plugged-in. I think that it is not charging even slightly.

Comment: If this laptop is 5 months old, it is still under warranty. Contact Lenovo support so they can walk you thru troubleshooting it and replace whatever is defective.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because:

1) Your charger is faulty and isn't supplying enough power

2) Your laptop is drawing too much power while on (high activity)

3) Your charging circuit or connections in the laptop is faulty

4) Related to 2), the laptop is getting too hot while on due to high activity

If it charges at a *normal* speed while off, it's possibly 2). If it charges slower than usual while off, it's possibly 1).